# Balancing two column table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, minipage, multirow, cellcolor

I am trying to recreate the following table using LaTeX

[image]

Here is what I have so far

[image]

My biggest problem is with balancing the two columns height wise (same height) as is done in the picture I am trying to recreate. In addition I have a problem that the surrounding box does not quite fit, and there is some bug that the table does not quite align to the left.

Any help fixing these issues would be much appreciated

## Code

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[bf]{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox,array,mathtools}

\colorlet{bodmas}{red}
\definecolor{algebra}{HTML}{4f81bd}

\newcommand{\headerstyle}{\cellcolor{algebra} \color{white} \bfseries}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\newcommand{\commutative}{%
\textbf{Commutative} property:
The order of elements does \textbf{not}
make any difference in the outcome. \newline
This is only true for \textbf{multiplication and addition}.
}
%
\newcommand{\distributive}{
\textbf{Distributive} property: The process of distributing a number
on the outside of the parentheses to each number on the inside; $a(b + c) = ab + ac$
}
%
\newcommand{\associative}{%
\textbf{Associative}: Grouping does \textbf{not} make any difference:
$(a+b) + c = a + (b + c)$, \newline $(ab)c = a(bc)$
}

\newcommand{\BODMAS}{
\textbf{Order of operations \textcolor{red}{BODMAS}}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Work within parentheses (), \textcolor{bodmas}{b}rackets [], and braces \{ \}
    from innermost and work outward.
    \item Simplify exponents/p\textcolor{bodmas}{o}wer and roots working from left 
    to right $\rightarrow$.
    \item Do \textcolor{bodmas}{d}ivision and \textcolor{bodmas}{m}ultiplication, whichever comes first
    left to right $\rightarrow$
    \item Do \textcolor{bodmas}{a}ddition and \textcolor{bodmas}{s}ubtraction, whichever comes first left to right 
    $\rightarrow$.
    \item Rounding off.
\end{enumerate}
}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\def\equOne{$a(b + c) = ab + c$}
\def\equTwo{$a(b - c) = ab - c$}
\def\equThree{$\Bigl(\cfrac{a}{b}\Bigr) = \cfrac{ad+bc}{bd}$}
\def\equFour{$\cfrac{(ab+ac)}{a} = b + c$}
\def\equFive{$a \neq 0$}
\def\equSix{$\Bigl(\cfrac{a}{b}\Bigr)-\Bigl(\cfrac{c}{d}\Bigr)=\cfrac{ad-bc}{bd} $}
\def\equSeven{$\cfrac{(a-b)}{(c-d)}=\cfrac{(b-a)}{(d-c)}$}
\def\equEight{$\cfrac{a}{(b/c)} = \cfrac{ac}{b}$}
\def\equNine{$\cfrac{(a+b)}{c} = \cfrac{a}{c} + \cfrac{b}{c}$}
\def\equTen{$\cfrac{\big(\cfrac{a}{b}\bigl)}{c} = \cfrac{a}{bc}$}
\def\equEleven{$a\Bigl(\cfrac{b}{c}\Bigr)=\cfrac{ab}{c}$}
\def\equTwelve{$\Bigl(\cfrac{a}{b}\Bigr)\biggl/\Bigl(\cfrac{c}{d}\Bigr)\biggr. = \cfrac{ad}{bc}$}
%
\node (table) [inner sep=0pt] {%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
    \begin{tabular}{c || c}%
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\headerstyle Algebraic Rules} \\ \arrayrulecolor{white} \hline \arrayrulecolor{algebra}%
    \begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth}%
        \begin{tabular}{p{\textwidth}}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\headerstyle Commutative, Associative and Distributive Laws} \\ \hline
        \commutative \\ \hline
        \distributive \\ \hline
        \associative  \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\headerstyle Order of Arithmetic Operations Rules} \\ \hline
        \BODMAS%
        \end{tabular}%
    \end{minipage} &%
    \begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}%
        \begin{tabular}{ P{0.5\textwidth} | P{0.5\textwidth}}%
         \multicolumn{2}{c}{\headerstyle Algebraic Operations Rules} \\ \hline
           \equOne\newline\noindent\equTwo & \equThree \\ \cline{1-2}
           \equFour\newline\equFive & \equSix \\\cline{1-2}
           \equSeven \newline Multiply top and bottom by $-1$ & \equEight \\\cline{1-2}
                                    \equNine & \equTen \\\cline{1-2}
                                    \equEleven & \equTwelve \\ \cline{1-2}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{tabular}
};
\draw [thick,color=algebra!50!black,rounded corners=.5em] (table.north west) rectangle (table.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You did not take into account the value of `\tabcolsep`, that is added on either side of a column, into account when determining the column widths of both inner tabulars.

Comment: I suggest using `matrix` of TikZ

Comment: @BlackMild Interesting! I made another attempt using `tcolorboxes` should I update my question with this attempt or post a new question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some further improvements are still needed but the following might serve as a place to start from:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[bf]{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox,array,mathtools}

\colorlet{bodmas}{red}
\definecolor{algebra}{HTML}{4f81bd}

\newcommand{\headerstyle}{\cellcolor{algebra} \color{white} \bfseries}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\newcommand{\commutative}{%
\textbf{Commutative} property:
The order of elements does \textbf{not}
make any difference in the outcome. \newline
This is only true for \textbf{multiplication and addition}.
}
%
\newcommand{\distributive}{
\textbf{Distributive} property: The process of distributing a number
on the outside of the parentheses to each number on the inside; $a(b + c) = ab + ac$
}
%
\newcommand{\associative}{%
\textbf{Associative}: Grouping does \textbf{not} make any difference:
$(a+b) + c = a + (b + c)$, \newline $(ab)c = a(bc)$
}

\newcommand{\BODMAS}{
\textbf{Order of operations \textcolor{red}{BODMAS}}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Work within parentheses (), \textcolor{bodmas}{b}rackets [], and braces \{ \}
    from innermost and work outward.
    \item Simplify exponents/p\textcolor{bodmas}{o}wer and roots working from left 
    to right $\rightarrow$.
    \item Do \textcolor{bodmas}{d}ivision and \textcolor{bodmas}{m}ultiplication, whichever comes first
    left to right $\rightarrow$
    \item Do \textcolor{bodmas}{a}ddition and \textcolor{bodmas}{s}ubtraction, whichever comes first left to right 
    $\rightarrow$.
    \item Rounding off.
\end{enumerate}
}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{12pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{12pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{P}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\def\equOne{$a(b + c) = ab + c$}
\def\equTwo{$a(b - c) = ab - c$}
\def\equThree{$\Bigl(\cfrac{a}{b}\Bigr) = \cfrac{ad+bc}{bd}$}
\def\equFour{$\cfrac{(ab+ac)}{a} = b + c$}
\def\equFive{$a \neq 0$}
\def\equSix{$\Bigl(\cfrac{a}{b}\Bigr)-\Bigl(\cfrac{c}{d}\Bigr)=\cfrac{ad-bc}{bd} $}
\def\equSeven{$\cfrac{(a-b)}{(c-d)}=\cfrac{(b-a)}{(d-c)}$}
\def\equEight{$\cfrac{a}{(b/c)} = \cfrac{ac}{b}$}
\def\equNine{$\cfrac{(a+b)}{c} = \cfrac{a}{c} + \cfrac{b}{c}$}
\def\equTen{$\cfrac{\big(\cfrac{a}{b}\bigl)}{c} = \cfrac{a}{bc}$}
\def\equEleven{$a\Bigl(\cfrac{b}{c}\Bigr)=\cfrac{ab}{c}$}
\def\equTwelve{$\Bigl(\cfrac{a}{b}\Bigr)\biggl/\Bigl(\cfrac{c}{d}\Bigr)\biggr. = \cfrac{ad}{bc}$}
%
\node (table) [inner sep=0pt] {%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{} || @{}c@{}}%
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\headerstyle Algebraic Rules} \\ \arrayrulecolor{white} \hline \arrayrulecolor{algebra}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.8\textwidth}%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{p{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\headerstyle Commutative, Associative and Distributive Laws} \\ \hline
        \commutative \\ \hline
        \distributive \\ \hline
        \associative  \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\headerstyle Order of Arithmetic Operations Rules} \\ \hline
        \BODMAS%
        \end{tabular}%
    \end{minipage} &%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{ 0{P{0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}} | P{0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}%
         \multicolumn{2}{c}{\headerstyle Algebraic Operations Rules} \\ \hline
           \equOne\newline\noindent\equTwo & \equThree \\ \cline{1-2}
           \equFour\newline\equFive & \equSix \\\cline{1-2}
           \equSeven \newline Multiply top and bottom by $-1$ & \equEight \\\cline{1-2}
                                    \equNine & \equTen \\\cline{1-2}
                                    \equEleven & \equTwelve \\ 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{tabular}
};
\draw [thick,color=algebra!50!black,rounded corners=.5em] (table.north west) rectangle (table.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks great, I was able to get closer using a few modifications. Any idea how I can make the rounded corners work? Atm the colors spill outside the tikzbox https://i.imgur.com/mBP8uZB.png