# Balancing two column table, part 2 (tcolorbox)

Tags: tcolorbox, columns

So I was unsure whether to update my old question: [Balancing two column table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550765/balancing-two-column-table?noredirect=1#comment1391234_550765)

Or create a new one. So I decided on the latter as this attempt is quite different from the previous one. As before I am trying to recreate this image roughly

[image]

With this attempt I tried to use the package [`tcolorbox`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) for the first time, and thus have some questions. My current best attempt looks like this

[image]

- Is the overal strategy good? I copied how to space the two columns equally from another answer.
- I still do not know how to remove the inner padding and margins properly. I tried with
  `size=small` but I still had to do some janky setup using `left=-1.5mm,right=-1.5mm,bottom=-1.5mm,top=-0.5mm` to remove the inner padding
- Similarly I was not able to horizontally align the equations and had to use a bunch of
  `hfil`'s everywhere. I tried setting `sidebyside align=center` but this had no affect.
- The top of the table have rounded corners, however the bottom does not. Is there a way to remedy this?
- I tried to make the three titles in the image the same height using `adjusted title` but this did not work. Any ideas?
- An idea to stack boxes with no spacing would be appreciated. Now I guess I have to guess (or look up the rule width, set the `bottomrule` to `0` and then subtract the rule width from `top=`
- Can the two column layout be done using rasters and 2 columns? I tried, but could not make it work and figured it was easier just using the `\tcblower`.

## Code

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,mathtools}
\usepackage[skins,raster,many]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\mylen}

\colorlet{bodmas}{red}
\definecolor{algebra}{HTML}{4f81bd}

\def\equOne{\hfil$a(b + c) = ab + c$\hfil}
\def\equTwo{\hfil$a(b - c) = ab - c$\hfil}
\def\equThree{\hfil$\Bigl(\cfrac{a}{b}\Bigr) = \cfrac{ad+bc}{bd}$\hfil}
\def\equFour{\hfil$\cfrac{(ab+ac)}{a} = b + c$\hfil}
\def\equFive{\hfil$a \neq 0$\hfil}
\def\equSix{\hfil$\Bigl(\cfrac{a}{b}\Bigr)-\Bigl(\cfrac{c}{d}\Bigr)=\cfrac{ad-bc}{bd} $\hfil}
\def\equSeven{\hfil$\cfrac{(a-b)}{(c-d)}=\cfrac{(b-a)}{(d-c)}$\hfil}
\def\equEight{\hfil$\cfrac{a}{(b/c)} = \cfrac{ac}{b}$\hfil}
\def\equNine{\hfil$\cfrac{(a+b)}{c} = \cfrac{a}{c} + \cfrac{b}{c}$\hfil}
\def\equTen{\hfil $\cfrac{\big(\cfrac{a}{b}\bigl)}{c} = \cfrac{a}{bc}$\hfil}
\def\equEleven{\hfil$a\Bigl(\cfrac{b}{c}\Bigr)=\cfrac{ab}{c}$\hfil}
\def\equTwelve{\hfil$\Bigl(\cfrac{a}{b}\Bigr)\biggl/\Bigl(\cfrac{c}{d}\Bigr)\biggr. = \cfrac{ad}{bc}$\hfil}

\newcommand{\commutative}{%
\textbf{Commutative} property:
The order of elements does \textbf{not}
make any difference in the outcome. \newline
This is only true for \textbf{multiplication and addition}.
}
%
\newcommand{\distributive}{
\textbf{Distributive} property: The process of distributing a number
on the outside of the parentheses to each number on the inside; $a(b + c) = ab + ac$.
}
%
\newcommand{\associative}{%
\textbf{Associative}: Grouping does \textbf{not} make any difference:
$(a+b) + c = a + (b + c)$, and $(ab)c = a(bc)$.
}

\newcommand{\BODMAS}{
\textbf{Order of operations \textcolor{red}{BODMAS}}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Work within parentheses (), \textcolor{bodmas}{b}rackets [], and braces \{ \}
    from innermost and work outward.
    \item Simplify exponents/p\textcolor{bodmas}{o}wer and roots working from left 
    to right $\rightarrow$.
    \item Do \textcolor{bodmas}{d}ivision and \textcolor{bodmas}{m}ultiplication, whichever comes first
    left to right $\rightarrow$
    \item Do \textcolor{bodmas}{a}ddition and \textcolor{bodmas}{s}ubtraction, whichever comes first left to right 
    $\rightarrow$.
    \item Rounding off.
\end{enumerate}
}

\begin{document}\noindent
  \begin{tcolorbox}[width=18cm,
    fonttitle=\Large \bfseries, title=Algebraic Rules, center title,
    colframe=algebra,
    size=small,boxrule=0.5mm,
    left=-1.5mm,right=-1.5mm,bottom=-1.5mm,top=-0.5mm
]
  \begin{tcbitemize}[raster equal height=rows,
                     raster every box/.style={fonttitle=\bfseries,
                                              colframe=algebra,valign=center,
                                              sharp corners},
                     ]
  \tcbitem[adjusted title={Commutative, Associative and Distributive Laws}]
  %
    \commutative
    
    \tcbline
    
    \distributive
    
    \tcbline
    
    \associative
    %
    \tcbsubtitle[before skip=0.5\baselineskip]{Order of Arithmetic Operations Rules}
    \BODMAS
    %
  \tcbitem[blankest, space to=\myspace,
           code={\setlength{\mylen}{\dimexpr \myspace/5}}]
  \begin{tcbitemize}[
    raster columns=1, raster row skip=0pt,
    raster every box/.append style={add to natural height=\mylen}]
    \tcbitem[sidebyside,center title,adjusted title={Algebraic Operations Rules},bottomrule=0cm]
        \equOne\newline\noindent\equTwo
        \tcblower
        \equThree
    \tcbitem[sidebyside,bottomrule=0cm,sidebyside align=center]
        \equFour\newline\equFive 
        \tcblower
        \equSix
    \tcbitem[sidebyside,bottomrule=0cm,sidebyside align=center]
        \equSeven
        \tcblower
        \equEight
    \tcbitem[sidebyside,bottomrule=0cm,sidebyside align=center]
        \equNine
        \tcblower
         \equTen
    \tcbitem[sidebyside,sidebyside align=center]
        \equEleven 
        \tcblower
        \equTwelve 
  \end{tcbitemize}
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```